# Image data Shows nil while retrieving image from JSON Array in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new in iOS. And I am trying to load images to custom `uitableviewcell` unfortunately not getting desired results.

In `didFinishLaunching` method

```
    imagearray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    imagearray=[responsedict valueForKey:@"EmpImg"];
    NSLog(@"Image Array =%@",imagearray);
```

Table View `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *STI=@"STI";
    NewJoineeCell *cell = (NewJoineeCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:STI];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewJoineeCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    NSData *imagedata=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[imagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] ];
    UIImage *image11=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imagedata];
    cell.propic.image=image11;

    return cell;

}
```

By Debugging imagedata Shows nil value while imagearray contain 13 objects

```
"http://url/UploadedFiles/MKsfdf.png"
```

Comment: Can you print your imageArray objects?

Comment: Is `[NSURL URLWithString:[imagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]` nil?

Comment: @Larme yes it showing nil

Comment: @user3182143 image array shows 13 objects and it print proper

Comment: You should download the image asynchronously by the way. Otherwise it will hit the UI hard

Comment: `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier` instead of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.... Why?

Comment: Not to mention, there is also no caching in your system which means that the app will download image for every cell, every time it appears. You should use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). It will take care of Asynchronous downloading and caching, without you doing any work at all.

Comment: @NSNoob SDWebImage Shows me error. Can you give me other hint rather then SDWebImage

Comment: These pointers are other than your main issue for improving performance of your app. NSData should not be null, it should instead freeze your UI until it finishes downloading so can't say what's happening with your code there except the curious bit in the way how you dequeue things. Why are you assigning your cell to a HeaderFooterView?

Comment: @Muju Which type of error you are getting while using SDWebImage?

Comment: What's the class of [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]?

Comment: @Larme Supposedly NSString since the OP says it contains strings of image URLs.

Comment: @NSNoob I suspect that it may be a NSArray with one element, or something like that. The OP needs to give more info since the NSURL is nil. Either the string URL is not valid, or it's just not a NSString object.

Comment: @Larme,@NSNoob Now it Showing Image. Error is Capturing 'self' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle